# ObjectMapper and Alamofire issue for Swift 3 Alamofire version for Alamofire 4

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire, objectmapper

I have recently migrated to `Swift` so please be patient and supportive.
I used the code from `Object Mapper` [github page](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper) correcting the Syntax for `Alamofire 4`

```
let URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper/d8bb95982be8a11a2308e779bb9a9707ebe42ede/sample_json"
Alamofire.request(URL).response { (response: DataResponse<WeatherResponse>) in

    let weatherResponse = response.result.value
    print(weatherResponse?.location)

    if let threeDayForecast = weatherResponse?.threeDayForecast {
        for forecast in threeDayForecast {
            print(forecast.day)
            print(forecast.temperature)           
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the following error as shown in screenshot.

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0):

This way you should call method in Alamofire :

```
func getWeatherDataResponseFromServer() {

        let URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper/d8bb95982be8a11a2308e779bb9a9707ebe42ede/sample_json"

        //AlamoFire request
        Alamofire.request(URL, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
            do {

                let reponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions()) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this gonna help you.

Comment: Thanks for helping me get the correct format but I need to model the response on completion please refer to this link https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper

Comment: then you should create your own completion handler method which return data in your format that i guess

Comment: the returned is written automatically into a model class